# Transformed image from GAE Images API upload to Facebook

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

**Does anyone know how to convert a GAE Images API Image object into a "file like object"?**

I'm trying to upload an image that I've transformed from the GAE Images API to Facebook. I'm using the execute_transforms function, which returns a "Image Representation" of the image. 
I've tried to upload it using the following code, but I get a FB API Error "No Uploaded Image"

```
img = images.Image(ORIGINAL_IMAGE)
img.crop(0.0, 5.0/img.height, 713.0/img.width, 644.0/img.height)
output = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
graph = fb.GraphAPI(access_token)
graph.put_photo(output, 'Look at this cool photo!')
```

I think the issue is that *output* is not a "file like object" which is what put_photo requires, but the GAE docs doesn't have a function for casting into a "file like object". Tried creating temp files and writing to them, but GAE doesn't allow writing to filesystem. I've also tried to write to a StringIO object, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use StringIO

```
enter code here

import StringIO

graph.put_photo(StringIO.StringIO(output), 'Look at this cool photo!')
```

Have a read of the docs at http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html